# How to fill a dataframe based on a condition over values in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

- `df_new`:

> ```
> time_start
> 0  1313575263
> 1  1313575263
> 2  1313575263
> 3  1313579775
> 4  1313579775
> ```

- `df_information`:

> ```
>  my_start value 
>  0  1313575263 foo  
>  1  1313579775 bar
> ```

I want to use the values in `df_information` to populate a new column in `df_new`. If `my_start` in `df_information` matches `time_start` in `df_new`, then use the corresponding `value` in `df_information` to populate `df_new`. Here is my desired output:

> ```
>  time_start value 
>  0  1313575263   foo 
>  1  1313575263   foo 
>  2  1313575263   foo 
>  3  1313579775   bar 
>  4  1313579775   bar
> ```

I figured a way to do this using two nested loops but since I am actually working with large dataframes, it takes a lot of time to run:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict1={'time_start':[1313575263,1313575263,1313575263,1313579775,1313579775]}
dict2={'my_start':[1313575263,1313579775],'value':['foo','bar']}

df_new=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=dict1)
df_information=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=dict2)

df_new['value']=np.nan

for index_new, row_new in df_new.iterrows():
    for index_information, row_information in df_information.iterrows():  
        if row_information['my_start']==row_new['time_start']:
            df_new['value'][index_new]=df_information['value'][index_information]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @Jezrael, Thanks for Duplicating this Question..That's the spirit..

Comment: @min2bro - 100% dupe, I first think data are different.

Comment: Thanks for pointing at the right post: `df_new['value'] = df_new['time_start'].map(df_information.set_index('my_start')['value'])` did the trick.